# how to store watched videos with react

Tags: reactjs

I got a question.
I'm building youtube based web, and got need help with storing watched videos of logged user

This is code of player

```
class VideoDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render(){
    const video = this.props.video;

    if(!video) {
      return <div />
    }

    const url = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${video.id.videoId}?autoplay=1`;

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <iframe className="Videoplayer" src={url} allowFullScreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2> {video.snippet.title}</h2>
          <div>{video.snippet.description}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default VideoDetails;
```

Comment: You can do this with redux.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a Redux store and either store it in localStorage or something like Firebase.